# Getting Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'

Tags: typescript, yaml, aws-cdk

I have installed `js-yaml` with this command

```
npm i @types/js-yaml
```

And my `package.json` looks like this

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/js-yaml": "^4.0.5",
  "aws-cdk-lib": "2.20.0",
  "constructs": "^10.0.0",
  "source-map-support": "^0.5.16",
  "ts-sync-request": "^1.4.1"
}
```

And my code doesn't show any error in `vscode`

```
import * as yml from 'js-yaml';
...
const metricsServerManifestUrl = 'https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml';
const manifest = yml.loadAll(new SyncRequestClient().get(metricsServerManifestUrl));
cluster.addManifest('metrics-server', manifest);
```

But I'm getting this error when I try to run application

> Error: Cannot find module 'js-yaml'

How can I fix this?

Comment: You installed the type definitions `@types/js-yaml`, but the actual package `js-yaml` seems to be missing. Did you try installing it? `npm install js-yaml`

Comment: yes. first I install that and it gives error in vscode. Could not find a declaration file for module 'js-yaml'. Try `npm i --save-dev @types/js-yaml` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'js-yaml';`

Comment: Did you try installing both `@types/js-yaml` and `js-yaml`?

Comment: installing both fix the issue. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@types/js-yaml` contains only type definitions used by TypeScript compiler to verify your code. However, it doesn't contain the actual implementation required at runtime.

You should install `npm install js-yaml --save`.